# Split list into multiple columns and append text python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, selenium

The below script:

```
company = "xyz"

prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li/div[@class='Market']")
    
    for price in prices:
        print (price.text)
```

Returns the below data in a single column:

```
    £85.00
    £230.13
    123
    456
    Buy
    £87.50
    £875.00
    123
    456
    Buy
    £96.25
    £192.50
    123
    456
    Buy
```

I'm trying to have it returned into .xls broken into 6 columns as below:

```
xyz £85.00 £230.13 123 456 Buy
xyz £87.50 £875.00 123 456 Buy
xyz £96.25 £192.50 123 456 Buy
```

The length of the list is unknown, although I can define a maximum if required

I have tried a number of pandas and numpy combinations, which is giving the illusion of being on the right track, but have become rather stuck.

***update***

Using:

```
company = 'xyz'
prices = [price.text.strip() for price in prices]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([company] * (len(prices)//5),
                   prices[::5], prices[1::5], prices[2::5], 
                   prices[3::5], prices[4::5]),
                    columns=['Company', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Output:

```
          Company
    0     xyz  ...   £96.25\n123\n456\n£192.50\nBuy
    1     xyz  ...  £100.00\n123\n456\n£100.00\nBuy
    2     xyz  ...  £125.00\n123\n456\n£125.00\nBuy
    3     xyz  ...  £150.00\n123\n456\n£150.00\nBuy
```

Comment: Please post what data `prices` actually gives

Comment: Sorry if I haven’t made that clearer but ’prices’ returns all the text above, in the second code box. It’s the text element for a number of list items from a html page

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
company = 'xyz'
prices = [[company] + price.text.strip().split() for price in prices]

df = pd.DataFrame(prices, columns=['Company', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Company        A    B    C        D    E
0     xyz   £96.25  123  456  £192.50  Buy
1     xyz  £100.00  123  456  £100.00  Buy
2     xyz  £125.00  123  456  £125.00  Buy
3     xyz  £150.00  123  456  £150.00  Buy
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien ... it broadly seems to work, although it seems to add all 3 data items into the same cell.....I've tried to also adapt it to include 5 data items but having the same issue.... any ideas?

    `company = "xyz"

    prices = [price.text.strip() for price in prices] 

    df = pd.DataFrame(zip([company] * (len(prices)//5), 

    prices[::5], prices[1::5], prices[2::5], prices[3::5], prices[4::5]), 

    columns=['Company', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) `

Comment: I've slightly amended the original request incase the comment above is hard to follow.... but yeah the issue was 5 items all going into the same cell

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `[price.text.strip() for price in prices]`. I'm not sure you have a list.

Comment: Have updated - I imagine where you're going is having to format `prices` as a list?

Comment: Output may show values not in the original list, sorry that's just because I took a snippet of the data, but the actual list is longer... I imagine the issue is the same though

Comment: Any ideas? Sorry have been stuck on this one :/

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope I understood your problem.

Comment: I think there's just one missing step. When `prices` is returned, in its initial form it comes as a webelement, not text, so I need to convert it before passing your answer. When I print(prices) instead of print(prices.text) the output is like this: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9b734fca34a73da0b071996a03d0dc5... etc. What's the best way to prepare it before answer do you think?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Can you share the url you try to scrape? Or mock the html code with your sample data.